# Flash course not showing when called by .net web app

Tags: .net, azure, flash, azure-blob-storage

I have a web app, written in .net MVC, hosted on Azure platform.

the plan is that the content is all stored on azure storage and referenced from the web app.

I have hit an issue though, when I call the flash via the app, it does not display at all. Nothing happens.

If I call the link directly though (http://storage.elearning-platform.net/courses/d89cbc10-e7d8-4fc2-9d23-087c88884d68/Simulation.htm), it fires up with no issues.

Is it a permissions thing? I have the relevant mime types set in IIS.

I'm lost. Please help.

thanks

Stephen

Comment: I have checked your SWF and there is nothing wrong with it even worked offline (away from browser using desktop FlashPlayer). I was worried that maybe the SWF doesnt like connecting from desktop to online (it's a famous Flash security issue headache). This leaves your app as suspect.. Have you ever loaded other SWFs with it fine before? Show the relevant loading code (C#? or VB?). Or start googling how to run Flash in a .NET application

Comment: Are you able to load other resources from azure storage into your App such as a image or web page other than the SWF, did you check the configuration for CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need check CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) configuration for your content stored in Azure Blob storage, please refer to this post for details - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx